# Bind highstock(highcharts) to live data?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using .net core 2.0 web socket to generate some data. I want to send the data to this chart and draw the chart. 
In the code below I want to show the live data without default values. I tried a lot but I wasn't successful. If I remove default value from 'series', chart will disappear. IS that possible to draw this chart on the fly?

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
global: {
    useUTC: false
}});

Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function () {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
},

rangeSelector: {
    buttons: [{
        count: 1,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '1M'
    }, {
        count: 5,
        type: 'minute',
        text: '5M'
    }, {
        type: 'all',
        text: 'All'
    }],
    inputEnabled: false,
    selected: 0
},

title: {
    text: 'Live random data'
},

exporting: {
    enabled: false
},

series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: (function () {
        // generate an array of random data
        var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

        for (i = -999; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push([
                time + i * 1000,
                Math.round(Math.random() * 100)
            ]);
        }
        return data;
    }())
}]});
```

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code. Currently there is not much we can do

Comment: See the example from the official website https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could find the solution. I needed to add xAxis property to my chart. By adding the code below, problem solved. Now it starts from current time.

```
xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: null,
                maxZoom: 10 * 1000,
                min: new Date().getTime()
            }
```